# Choose Your Power Wisely?

Tags: logical-deduction, situation

You were walking in your home, when suddenly out of nowhere a genie appeared in front of you and gave you multiple wishes of his own , but only asked you to choose only one of them :-

(i) Infinite Will-Power

(ii) Teleporting

(iii) Mind-reading .

(iv) Time Travelling .

(v) Power to Fly .

(vi) Power to Change Forms .

(vii) Immortality .

(viii) Power to read the Future .

You see that every power, in some way, is useful for you, but the genie says you can choose only one power from them. If you want to get the most use out of it , which power will you choose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time traveling, Then you can go back in time. Meet the Genie again several times and get the rest of the powers.

Answer (score 1):

The power to change form because you can turn into the genie and grant your self the rest of the powers. It doesn't say that the genie can't grant him self powers.

Comment: Good answer , what if the genie can't grant him self-powers?

Comment: Then he should choose infinite will power to make the genie give him the other powers.